# Average rating from firebase database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-api-3

> Edit: So I tried writting my own code so that i could post it here. I
>   somehow managed to read all the ratings for one location and then
>   calculate the average and save that average in the database again.
>   Everything works fine, but when I refresh the app it crashes with an
>   error: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type
>   com.example.getlocation.MarkerLocation. But it calculates the average
>   and saves it in the database. So I guess we're progressing at leat a
>   little bit.

Every user add locations to the database under the title like location1, location2,... as you can see below. Every location is then read from the database and dispalyed on the map. Each user can rate locations diplayed on the map on a star ratingBar from 0 to 5 stars. The rating of each user is saved in the database under that user's Uid as a child of the rating node. What I need to do is to calculate average rating of each location and then somehow display it. I can manage that part myself. Just need to calculate the average.

So this is what my database looks like:

In the screenshot everything look fine but in the json there is a null where it's supposed to say

https://ibb.co/Rc7DgRv - screenshot

json:

```
{
  "location" : {
    "location1" : {
      "Title" : "location1",
      "UserID" : "EuvmA4ep8jV87qC9Y3suouoGENI2",
      "latitude" : 63.326310173826165,
      "longitude" : 33.58473535627127,
      "rating" : {
        "EuvmA4ep8jV87qC9Y3suouoGENI2" : {
          "Rating" : 1
        },
        "bLpa0j4RDqfBcMQ5agWAi1zxJyD3" : {
          "Rating" : 5
        }
      }
    },
    "location2" : {
      "Title" : "location2",
      "UserID" : "bLpa0j4RDqfBcMQ5agWAi1zxJyD3",
      "latitude" : 54.820477453850884,
      "longitude" : 42.054178789258,
      "rating" : {
        "bLpa0j4RDqfBcMQ5agWAi1zxJyD3" : {
          "Rating" : 2
        }
      }
    },
    "marker rating" : [ null, {
      "average rating" : {
        "current" : 3
              }
            } ]
          }
        }
```

here's my code:

```
double Rating = Double.parseDouble(valueOf(addedRatingBar.getRating()));

    MarkerRating markerRating = new MarkerRating(Rating);
    mRating.child("location").child(String.valueOf(markerTitle.getText())).child("rating").child(user.getUid()).child("Rating").setValue(markerRating.Rating);


    final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("location");
    final DatabaseReference dbRef = db.child(String.valueOf(markerTitle.getText())).child("rating");

    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            double total = 0.0;
            double count = 0.0;
            double average = 0.0;

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                double rating = Double.parseDouble(ds.child("Rating").getValue().toString());
                total = total + rating;
                count = count + 1;
                average = total / count;

            }

            final DatabaseReference newRef = db.child("marker rating").child(String.valueOf(markerTitle.getText())).child("average rating");
            newRef.child("current").setValue(average);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
  }
});
```

I hope this time it's better and someone will answer because Ipm getting really confused

Comment: And what is your question? How to parse json, how to read values from a DB, how to calculate that average???

Comment: I want to calculate the average and then somehow display it. But i don't know how to read all the rating values for each location so that i could calculate the average @GhostCat

Comment: You already said that. But which step exactly. You put JSON example data. Do you have that data, and want to parse it? Again: we only have what you write up here. And so far, it is **not** clear which exact steps you have taken, and where you are blocked.

Comment: Sorry but I don't really know what parse means. Im not that good in english. And I don't know how to say it but i have All that data in database and I only want to retrieve something like a list of the values in the rating node and calculate the average. But I feel like that's again the same thing I already said and I didn't help at all. @GhostCat

Comment: @MišoBendík The one thing we all have in common here is that we're developers, so we like working with code. If you add the code of what you've already tried to your question (there is an edit link right under it), you'll find that it's much more likely that folks can/will answer.

Comment: As I suggested on your prior identical and closed question, please include the code of what you tried. I also previously mentioned that you have several options for getting the average; either reading in the location node and iterating over the child nodes to get the values, then creating an average *or* read in one node at a time using child_added and then create the average. You're going to need to show what you've tried; I suggest reviewing the Firebase Guide on [Working with Lists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data) and see what you can come up with.

Comment: @Frank I edited my post and posted my code. But I don't think that it will solve anything

Comment: Your code is not attaching the listener to the database yet, so your `onDataChange` will never be fired. You'll need to call `addSingleValueEventListener` on one of your `...Ref` variables (I'm not sure which one). Note that it'll be a lot easier to help if you limit the code to what is relevant to your question. Since you're asking how to calculate an average, the code about markers seems unrelated. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more hints on how to make it easier to help you.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This time it has to be good. I hope.

Answer (score 1):

You're dividing by the number of results at every iteration, which gives you a moving average. Say that you have 5 child nodes, with values 1...5. You current code does the following at each iteration of the loop:

- current: 1, total: 1, average = 1 / 1 = 1
- current: 2, total: 3, average = 3 / 2 = 1.5
- current: 3, total: 6, average = 6 / 3 = 2
- current: 4, total: 10, average = 10 / 4 = 2.5
- current: 5, total: 15, average = 15 / 5 = 3

You should actually only get the average **after** the loop, when you'd gotten the sum of all nodes. So:

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    long total = 0;

    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        long rating = Double.parseDouble(ds.child("Rating").getValue(Long.class));
        total = total + rating;
    }
    double average = (double)total / dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
}
```

This fixes a few more problems too:

- The values in your database are whole numbers, so you should get them with `getValue(Long.class)`.
- No longer converts the numbers to a string, so they can be summed.
- Gets the count of child nodes with `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()` instead of counting them in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase Function to listen when creating a new rating in your node

and for every new rate, you calculate  avg and number of rating 
and saved into parent node like this .. I hope this help

```
"location" : {
    "location1" : {
      "Title" : "location1",
      "UserID" : "EuvmA4ep8jV87qC9Y3suouoGENI2",
      "latitude" : 63.326310173826165,
      "longitude" : 33.58473535627127,
      "ratingAvg" : 3,
      "numOfrating" : 2,
      "rating" : {
        "EuvmA4ep8jV87qC9Y3suouoGENI2" : {
          "Rating" : 1
        },
        "bLpa0j4RDqfBcMQ5agWAi1zxJyD3" : {
          "Rating" : 5
        }
  }
}
```